# Flutter: how to retrieve array of image from firestore Database to carousel

Tags: arrays, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on flutter project, I have stored my images on fire store as array that contain URLs of image. I want to retrieve those URLs and display them on my app.

I used the whole day to try to solve this issue but nothing worked.
I need help guys.

[the image show the collection and the document that have array of URLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvQx1.png)

the code below works fine on normal document but when I pass array so as to be displayed on carousel return error

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


import 'screens/add_image.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // List<NetworkImage> _listOfImages = <NetworkImage>[];
  Future getImageFirestore() async {
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("imageFie").get();
    return qn.docs;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Retrieve Image In Carousel')),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context)
                .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddImage()));
          },
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            FutureBuilder(
                future: getImageFirestore(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapShot) {
                  return snapShot.data == null
                      ? Container()
                      : Column(
                          children: [
                            CarouselSlider.builder(
                                itemCount: snapShot.data.length,
                                options: CarouselOptions(
                                  initialPage: 0,
                                  autoPlay: true,
                                ),
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index,
                                    int pageViewIndex) {
                                  DocumentSnapshot images =
                                      snapShot.data[index];
                                 
                                  return Image.network(
                                    images['imageUrlList'],
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                  );
                                }

                                
                                ),
                            
                          ],
                        );
                })
          ],
        ));

  
  }
}
```

Comment: please provide the error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
DocumentSnapshot images = snapShot.data[index];

return Image.network(
  images['imageUrlList'],
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
);
```

with

```
Map images = snapShot[index].data();
return Image.network(
  images['imageUrlList'][0],
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
);
```

The above code will build a carousel using the first images of all documents in imageFie.